# Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ equal the number of alpha particle emissions of carbon-14 that are counted by a Geiger counter each second. Assume that the distribution of $X$ is Poisson with mean $16$. Let $W$ equal the time in seconds before the
seventh count is made.

(a) Give the distribution of $W$.

(b) Find $\Pr(W \le 0.5)$. Hint: Use Equation 3.2-1 with $\lambda w = 8$.

I got and understood part a (I think), however for part b I am a bit confused as to why you would have to solve for both $\Pr(N=7)$ and $\Pr(N=8)$.  For this you would just do $1 - e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$, correct?

Comment: The time before the 7th count is made is actually not Poisson distributed but rather Gamma distributed, specifically with shape parameter $7$ and scale parameter $1/16$. This follows because the times between events in a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ are exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$ and hence with mean $1/\lambda$.

Comment: However, the second part can still be done with the Poisson distribution, because the number of events in any fixed time interval of length $T$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda T$. So it is enough to compute $P(N \geq 7)$ where $N$ has a certain Poisson distribution.

Comment: I'm slightly confused on computing this still thought the point of the gamma distribution was to avoid using integration by parts.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out thanks alot in advance!